# How to solve a problem with time in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have such a problem. I have a code:

```
def send_output(self):
return list(map("Printer - {}".format, self.Product))
```

And it shows me:

```
Printer - Canon
Printer - Lexmark
Printer - HP
etc...
```

I'd like this code to show me the same infos, but with *present time* like below:

```
Printer - Canon - 21:17:07
Printer - Lexmark - 21:17:09
Printer - HP - 21:17:14
etc...
```

I was trying to use **strftime('%H:%M:%S')** somehow...

I added at the begining:

```
from time import strftime
```

and also

```
self._time = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

and put it into my code like that:

```
def send_output(self):
return list(map("Printer - {} - {}".format, self.Product, self._time))
```

But it doesn't show me all informations I want. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Obviously the code that you posted belongs to the method of some class. What is the type of that class'es `_time` member?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This should be a snippet of code that we can copy and paste then run ourselves and get the same output you currently get.

Comment: *"doesn't show me what I want"* - What *does* it show you?

Answer (score 0):

In the way you implemented it, `self._time` will only get executed when you instantiate the class, hence I assume it's displaying the same time value for all your printers.

Instead you should implement it as a property method --

```
@property
def _time(self):
    return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Some more help about it?